# Edit the .csproj file in Xamarin Studio

Tags: xamarin-studio, csproj

I am trying to edit the .csproj file in Xamarin studio. I went to open the .csproj through the directory but it just opens my Xamarin android solution and no file is shown. How can I access the .csproj file in Xamarin studio?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you open it into the text editor.

In the file open dialog you need to select Source Code Editor in the Open With drop down box.

By default it will open with the Solution Workbench.

Another way to open the .csproj file into the text editor is to right click the project in the Solution window and select Tools - Edit File.